# Desktop/OS User Agents in Javascript

Tags: javascript, user-agent

Below is my current script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('BlackBerry')!= -1){
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/m/css/mobile.css" type="text/css" />');
} else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone')!= -1) {
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/m/css/smartmobile.css" type="text/css" />');
}else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android')!= -1) {
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/m/css/smartmobile.css" type="text/css" />');
} else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Windows XP')!= -1) {
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/m/css/smartmobile.css" type="text/css" />');
}
else{
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/m/css/mobile.css" type="text/css" />');
}
</script>
```

The Windows XP is not working, and it's defaulting to the last else clause on a desktop computer. I need either the OS IDs or the browser's IDs (i .e firefox, chrome, IE, opera).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "**Windows XP**" line is not working as Windows XP identifies itself as "**Windows NT 5.1**".

However, I'm curious as to why you'd want to do this at all. UserAgent sniffing in any form is generally frowned upon in the web-development community - there's always a far better (usually far easier) way.

Comment: It's for our mobile website. I want a certain CSS to show for Blackberrys and another for the smarter phones. I can not use any server side coding sadly.

Comment: Why is it frowned upon? I think its fairly common, so you can direct users to a version of your site which supports their environment.

Comment: @Bry4n you can use CSS media queries to do that without browser-sniffing. See: http://vimeo.com/12976832 http://www.alistapart.com/articles/pocket/

Comment: @Nate It's frowned upon for a large number of reasons - mostly because it's a maintenance nightmare requiring you to constantly maintain and update a list of browser support, but also because the alternative methods are all easier and cleaner and more reliable. See: http://css-tricks.com/browser-detection-is-bad/ http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/05/31/why-browser-sniffing-stinks/

Comment: @Nate: Internet Explorer is fairly common, yet frowned upon by everyone.